# C# WebApi Query Parameter Parsing

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, query-string, querystringparameter

I have a query string coming in from a jquery grid that I am trying to parse into parameters within C# Web API, but I am unable to get one of the properties to populate.

Query String:

```
?current=1&rowCount=10&sort[received]=desc&sort[email]=asc&sort[id]=desc&searchPhrase=
```

Method:

```
public IEnumerable<IUserDto> Get(int current, int rowCount, NameValueCollection sort, string searchPhrase)
```

The 'sort' parameter is always null, all others populate correctly. I have tried multiple types for the parameter but no matter what I have tried I always end up with a null parameter.

Any direction or suggestion on parameter type would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deserialize a complex aggregate value, such as a `NameValueCollection` from a query string, you need to decorate the parameter with a `FromUriAttribute`. This does not guarantee that it will work by any means but otherwise it will not work unless you have defined a custom parameter handler.

```
public IEnumerable<IUserDto> Get(
    int current,
    int rowCount,
    [FromUri] NameValueCollection sort,
    string searchPhrase
) { ... }
```

Also, you need to make sure that what you are serializing into your URL is actually a dictionary in JSON format. From the URL you posted, it looks like you are adding the `received`, `id`, and `email` properties from a local object as individual query string parameters

```
&sort[received]=desc&sort[email]=asc&sort[id]=desc
```

WebAPI's parameter binding is not going to automatically aggregate these into a dictionary for you.

You can build it like

```
var sortParam = ['received', 'id', 'email'].reduce(function (o, key) {
  o[key] = sort[key];
  return o;
}, {});

var queryParams = '?current=' + 1 + 
                  '&rowCount' = 10 + 
                  '&sort=' + JSON.stringify(sortParam) +
                  '&searchPhrase=' + something;
```

I would also suggest changing the order so that the `sort` parameter is last.

Comment: I attempted the solution but the sort parameter is still coming back as null, I also tried;
`[FromUri] Dictionary[string, string] sort`
`[FromUri] List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> sort`

Comment: ^^ meant `[FromUri] Dictionary<string,string> sort`